# If using Azure Synapse Analytics in a new project - is it best to use Synapse Pipelines over ADF, or are there major considerations?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-synapse-pipeline

We're moving from on-premise to Azure and will be using Azure Synapse. Our transformations will largely be lift-and-shift of SQL stored procs to start.

Looking at the high-level documentation, I'm not seeing any differences between ADF & Azure Synapse Pipelines that would matter for our use case: [MS Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/data-integration/concepts-data-factory-differences)

Given we'll be using Azure Synapse Analytics, does it make the most sense to use Synapse Pipelines over ADF, just to be a bit more streamlined, or are there other considerations?

i.e. could pricing be totally different, documentation/support (I assume ADF would be better...but maybe they're so similar it's a moot point), etc.

Comment: There are a few use cases that are supported by Data Factory but not in Synapse. My advice would be to use Synapse unless your use case is not supported. I don't know all those use cases. I see one answer below with 2 of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything depends on how you want to design and architect because there are still couple of discrepancies between Synapse pipelines and ADF:

1. IRs cannot be shared between Synapse workspaces unlike ADFs
2. AIRFlow integration and Power Query are in ADf and still not in synapse

https://azurede.com/2021/03/27/difference-between-synapse-pipelines-and-azure-data-factory-pipelines/